# What is the connection between the manga and movie of "Abyss of Hyperspace"?

Tags: bodacious-space-pirates

When I watched the anime *Bodacious Space Pirates*, I learned that it was based on the Light Novel series *Miniskirt Space Pirates*. However, there was also a sequel movie planned called *Abyss of Hyperspace*.

While I was looking at the Yuricon website, I found a listing for [*Bodacious Space Pirates: Abyss of Hyperspace* Vol. 1](http://www.yuricon.com/product/bodacious-space-pirates-abyss-of-hyperspace-vol-1/).

So I am wondering what is the connection between the manga and movie of *Miniskirt Space Pirates: Abyss of Hyperspace*? Are they an adaptation of one another or are they continuing their own media (the manga follows the light novel while the movie follows the anime)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For *Abyss of Hyperscape*, the manga is an adaptation of the movie.**

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bodacious_Space_Pirates#Manga) mentioned about this in a brief,

> A manga adaptation of the film illustrated by Chibimaru began serialization in Media Factory's Monthly Comic Alive from February 2014.

---

However, the confusion between the continuity between the manga and the anime might arise because the anime overtook the original source (light novel)'s progress.

From [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%9F%E3%83%8B%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AB%E5%AE%87%E5%AE%99%E6%B5%B7%E8%B3%8A#%E3%83%86%E3%83%AC%E3%83%93%E3%82%A2%E3%83%8B%E3%83%A1),

> 原作の第3巻がまだあらすじしかできていない時期にアニメ化の企画が動き始めたため、第1話から第18話までは原作の第1巻から第3巻までに準拠した内容となっており、第19話以降は時系列的に現時点ではアニメオリジナルエピソードとなっている（原作10巻巻末時点で、まだ2年目の6月末）。また、当初は2011年後半に放送が予定されていたものが2012年にずれこんだ。そういった時間的余裕もあり、第1話の放送前に全26話の制作を完了した。制作に余裕を持てた状況も、前述のような異色の展開や実験に寄与している。原作のスペースオペラ的側面はやや薄められており、異星人的な種族などは登場しない。ただし最古参の海賊が存命しているなど、原作の要素は残っていたり、アニメ版からの逆輸入設定も有る。
>
> Since the anime's production planning was about to start when the 3rd volume of the original source (light novel) had only a summary, episode 1-18 would be based on volume 1-3, and episode 19 and later would be anime original story based on the present time chronologically. However, while the broadcast was planned to start in the second-half of 2011, it was delayed until 2012. Because of the time allowance, the production for the whole 26 episodes has finished before episode 1 was broadcast. Moreover, the time allowance made it possible for the production to contribute to the different plot development and experiments. The "space opera" feeling from the original source was reduced, and alien-like races were not introduced. However, regarding the oldest pirate being alive and more, some plot from the original source still remained, but also some of the settings from the anime got adapted into the light novel too.

To summarize:

- The light novel was adapted into a manga, and partially into an anime.
- The anime continued with an original story while the light novel was still in progress.
- The movie continued the anime, and a new manga adapted it.

Comment: i didn't know the anime overtook the light novel. really hoping that the part with Jenny and Lynn and how Chika is so into Marika are from the light novel